# Do my emotional choices affect the story?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

I am playing Golden Sun: Dark Dawn and noticed that sometimes I need to give an emotional response to something that was said. Do these decisions affect anything ? Or are they purely aesthetic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the decisions really make a difference; they're just there to let you develop your character's identity a little. Pretty much the same things will happen regardless of how you respond, but it serves as a nice aesthetic touch.

If you want a reference, I quote the following from a [review](http://rreload.com/review-golden-sun-dark-dawn):

> The player is allowed to "respond" at certain points with one of 4 emotional responses (positive, enthusiastic, negative, or angry). While this has little impact on the actual game, it adds a bit of the player's personality into the otherwise mysterious silent character.

Comment: That's what I figured - I didn't see it being as nuanced as something like Mass Effect, but I wanted to make sure. Didn't want to burn any unnecessary bridges or anything. XD

Comment: @DerpyHooves If you played the first two games you'd probably find it it was weird (and funny) when all of a sudden Felix (main character for the second game) wasn't talking and Issac (main character for the first game) was blabbing away. xD

Comment: Having played each game in the series multiple times, I can attest to there not being a story difference in these choices; however, choosing unexpected responses did lead to some humorous dialogue in the first two, especially the second, which keeps track of every time you disagree with a certain character, who has a big reaction after you do it too many times. Still, that's an easter egg, and the character goes back to normal after that.